# Debye temperature for the steel?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, phonons, data

I'm looking for data on Debye temperature of steel (ideally with a known carbon concentration, structure, and set of phases), but find only data on elements. Do You happen to meet the data in papers, or textbooks?

Comment: Perhaps here?   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9781441999788-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1326037-p174117366&ei=MHLBUrHmAq7LsATHmoGQDg&usg=AFQjCNGMQIYKUe0dFWRW4PeKa9Be7xbzZw&sig2=Amux9F7pHJJcHKx1_HRGsA

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: It's number two hit by google searching for "debye temperature of steel". Of course I tried that. No the doc doesn't have debye temperature of steel. Nor any doc on first n pages of the search.

Comment: @Alexander: third google's hit of "debye temperature of steel" is a wikipedia article: [Debye model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model) -- and there's no such information there. Can You give a link?

Comment: @Alexander: I saw this doc, and even read the table, but missed the part that the some of the alloys listed are actually stainless steels. Please make it an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debye temperatures of some steel alloys can be found in the thesis of Rajevac, Vedran:
["Lattice dynamics in Hydrogenated Austenitic Stainless Steels and in the Superionic Conductor Cu 2-δ Se"](http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/523/) on p. 43.

[image]

In general searching for material specific data I recommend starting with a search in Google, Google Scholar and Landolt-Boernstein. If neither turn up anything it might still be an open research question.

Answer (score 1):

J Phys Condens Matter. 2010 Feb 10;22(5):055402 :
"The Debye temperature, Θ(D), of Fe(100-x)Cr(x) disordered alloys with 0 ≤ x ≤ 99.9 was determined from the temperature dependence of the centre shift of (57)Fe Mössbauer spectra recorded in the temperature range of 60-300 K. Its compositional dependence shows an interesting non-monotonous behaviour. For 0 < x <= ~ 45 as well as for ∼ 75 ≤ x ≤ ∼ 95, the Debye temperature is enhanced relative to its value of a metallic iron, and at x ≈ 3 there is a local maximum having a relative height of ∼ 12% compared to a pure iron. For ∼ 45 ≤ x ≤ ∼ 75 and for x ≥ ∼ 95 the Debye temperature is smaller than the one for the metallic iron, with a local minimum at x ≈ 55 at which the relative decrease of Θ(D) amounts to ∼ 12%. The first maximum coincides quite well with that found for the spin-waves stiffness coefficient, D(o), while the pretty steep decrease observed for x ≥ ∼ 95, which is indicative of a decoupling of the probe Fe atoms from the underlying chromium matrix, is likely related to the spin-density waves which constitute the magnetic structure of chromium in that interval of composition and show also anomalous dynamic behaviour. The harmonic force constant calculated from the effective Debye temperature of the least Fe-concentrated alloy (x ≥ 99.9) amounts to only 23% of the one characteristic of a pure chromium as determined from the heat capacity experiment."

And the Debye temperature of iron is about 470K.

Comment: I found data on AlTi and many others, but not the steel. Which is very strange, given that steel is the main construction material for some hundered years or so, and it's Debye temperature gives us idea about the ratio of electron to lattice thermoconductivity at the given temperature.

Comment: Yep, one expects non-linear behaviour of Debye temperature as a function of concentration. Although not as drastic as 77% reduction due to 0.1% of Fe in Cr. That's really something.